# How to configure Spark / Databricks memory to collect large R data.frame?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

Out of memory issues caused by collecting spark DataFrame into R data.frame has been discussed here several times (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50224272/spark-how-collect-large-amount-of-data-without-out-of-memory) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30645507/sparkr-collect-method-crashes-with-outofmemory-on-java-heap-space/30678093#30678093)). However, none answer seems to be usable in my environment.

**Problem:**

I'm trying to collect some transactional data using `inSample <- collect(read.parquet(inSamplePath))` (the `read.parquet` from `SparkR` library). My driver has 256 GB RAM. The sample data is smaller than 4 GB (when in uncompressed CSV, the parquet is much smaller), but command is failing with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit` error.

**Environment and Data :**

- Azure Databricks cluster with Standard_E32s_v3 driver node (256 GB RAM) and 2 - 8 Standard_D16s_v3 workers
- Input data is stored as parquet files in Azure Datalake Gen2
- Raw data size ~4GB (mix of integers, strings and doubles; the data is originating in a upstream transactional SQL DB thus structure is quite clean, none string exceeds 256 length)

**Attempted Resolution:**

- Cluster Spark Config: `spark.driver.maxResultSizei 128g`
- Cluster Environment variable: `JAVA_OPTS="-Xms120G -Xmx120G -XX:MaxPermSize=8G -XX:PermSize=4G"`
- Script configuration (tested when using `sparklyr`) `config$spark.driver.memory` (set to 120G)

None of the attempts helped. **I must be missing some configuration property that allocates memory to local R. Please recommend which server configuration(s) or environment variable(s) should be changed.**

---

**EDIT:**

- Another option tested w/o success:

  - Updated to Spark 3.0
  - spark.driver.memory 130g
  - spark.driver.memoryOverhead 62g *(added based on [Spark 3.0 configuration description](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#:%7E:text=Spark%20provides%20three%20locations%20to%20configure%20the%20system%3A,address%2C%20through%20the%20conf%2Fspark-env.sh%20script%20on%20each%20node.))*
  - spark.driver.maxResultSize 64g
- Capacity validation: input can be collected (`val x = myInput.collect`) when using Spark Scala even for maxResultSize 16g; issue is restricted to R module only

Comment: did you find out how to solve this?

Comment: @Dipperman no - gave up some accuracy to partition the input to fit. Not a great solution.

Comment: Are you using the `databricks-connect` client library to handle the back-end? I am working through a similar issue currently with the azure/databricks support team, I think our problems have the same root cause

Comment: @MattSummersgill no, just keeping code in the Databricks notebook(s). I believe the behavior will be the same (issue is happening when cluster is executing the code, code origin hopefully doesn't matter). I'll try to test databricks-connect as soon as I'm out of current fire-drill and share results. Please keep me posted about your findings too.

Comment: @Dan - I'll keep you posted if my investigation bears any fruit. I was able to get this down to a relatively minimal example that generates it's own data here: https://gist.github.com/msummersgill/fb61204b73c2bebcaf5a1fe299172b45